# How can I solve this Exception main” org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable ?, C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("test123");       
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).Click();
```

Also I'm using ImplicitWait command, thread and still facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard

Element is not reachable by keyboard in plain words means that the element can’t be reached using the keyboard, which means you won't physically interact with it even.

Reason

There can be multiple reasons behind the error Element is not reachable by keyboard which can be either of the following:

The element is hidden as modern JavaScript-centric UI styles always keep the ugly raw HTML input field hidden. The hidden attribute could have been implemented through either of the following ways:
A temporary overlay of some other element over the desired element.
A permanent overlay of some other element over the desired element.
Presence of attributes e.g. class="ng-hide", style="display: none", etc
As per best practices while sending character sequence, you must not attempt to invoke click() or sendKeys() on any

or  tag, instead invoke click() on the desired  tag following the Official locator strategies for the webdriver.
Solution

There are different approaches to address this issue.

Incase of temporary overlay use WebDriverWait inconjunction with ExpectedConditions for the desired element to be visible/clickable as follows:

```csharp
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]"))).click();
```

In case of permanent overlay use executeScript() method from JavascriptExecutor interface as follows:

```csharp
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+inputText+"')"
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, myElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

While working in qa company, I have experienced this problem in many automation projects. There are multiple solutions to handle this blocker -

**Solution 1 -**
Use Javascript Executor:

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("test123");       
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).Click();
 
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]"));
IJavaScriptExecutor JsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
JsExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**Solution 2 -**
Using Keyboard Events:

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("test123");       
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).Click();

driver.findElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

**Solution 3 -**
Using Action class:

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("test123");       
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).Click();

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]"));          
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();
```

**Solution 4 -**
By Double Click the Submit button:

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("test123");       
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).Click();

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]"));          
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.MoveToElement(element).DoubleClick().Perform();
```

**Solution 5 -**
Using Co-ordinates [Least Preferred]:

```csharp
driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("test");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("test123");       
// driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]")).Click();

IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id="btnSubmit"]"));          
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.move_by_offset(X coordinates, Y coordinates).click().perform()
```

where 'X' & 'Y' coordinates should be known.